# how to change indentation settings in jupyter notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

```
$ jupyter  --version
Selected Jupyter core packages...
IPython          : 8.20.0
ipykernel        : 6.29.0
ipywidgets       : 8.1.1
jupyter_client   : 8.6.0
jupyter_core     : 5.7.1
jupyter_server   : 2.12.5
jupyterlab       : 4.0.11
nbclient         : 0.8.0
nbconvert        : 7.14.2
nbformat         : 5.9.2
notebook         : 7.0.7
qtconsole        : 5.5.1
traitlets        : 5.14.1
```

I try to change `Settings`->`Text Editr Indentation`, but it affects only the editor but not the notebook.
This does not depend on whether I open the notebook in a separate browser tab or Jupiterlab.

Where is notebook settings?